# problem with mapping and created tables when using playframework

Tags: java, jpa, mapping, playframework

I tried to create a webapp consisting of `shoppingcart` and `cartitem`s using `playframework`.I created the following mappings and when I tried to run the webapp,I found that the `postgres db` tables created does not have the values ,which creates a bidirectional association.

```
@Entity
public class CartItem extends Model implements Comparable<CartItem>
   @OneToOne
   public Product pdt;

   @ManyToOne
   public ShoppingCart cart;

   public int quantity;
...   
}

@Entity
public class ShoppingCart extends Model {   
    @OneToOne
    public MyUser customer;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cart", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<CartItem> cartItems;
    public ShoppingCart(MyUser customer) {
    super();
        this.customer = customer;
    this.cartItems = new TreeSet<CartItem>();
    }
...
}
```

When I added the cartitem to cart,

```
public static void addItemToCart(Long productId,Long cartId,String quantity) {              
        Product pdt = Product.findById(productId);
        ShoppingCart cart = ShoppingCart.findById(cartId);      
        int qty = Integer.parseInt(quantity);
        System.out.println("create cartitem from "+qty +" copies of product="+pdt.getName()+" for user="+cart.getCustomer().getEmail());

        CartItem cartItem = new CartItem(pdt,qty);
        cart.addItem(cartItem);
        cart.save();
        redirect("/");
    }
```

When this method was executed  during post, the println() statement produced

```
create cartitem from 3 copies of product=Product1 for user=jon@gmail.com
```

The tables created showed this data

```
select * from shoppingcart ;
 id  | customer_id 
-----+-------------
 191 |         151
(1 row)

select * from cartitem ;
 id  | quantity | product_id | cart_id 
-----+----------+------------+---------
 192 |        3 |     168    |        
(1 row)
```

**The cart_id column has no value**.Is there some problem in the way I defined my mappings? Can someone help me resolve this?

below is the table schema as given by \d in psql

```
\d cartitem
    Table "public.cartitem"
  Column  |  Type   | Modifiers 
----------+---------+-----------
 id       | bigint  | not null
 quantity | integer | not null
 product_id  | bigint  | 
 cart_id  | bigint  | 
Indexes:
    "cartitem_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk4393e7353ab523e" FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product(id)
    "fk4393e7355396066" FOREIGN KEY (cart_id) REFERENCES shoppingcart(id)
```

**update:**
I made this work by

```
cartItem.setCart(cart);//why do I have to do this?
```

Now,after I save the cart, the cartitem table has

```
select * from cartitem;
 id  | quantity | product_id | cart_id 
-----+----------+------------+---------
 197 |        4 |     164    |     196
(1 row)
```

So,I think the bidirectional association doesn't work..
Does someone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Right after

```
cart.addItem(cartItem);
```

Try adding

```
cartItem.cart = cart;
cartItem.save();
```

Comment: I made it work by explicitly calling 'cartItem.setCart(cart)..'that should have happened because of the bidirectional association in mapping..

Answer (score 0):

because of efficiency,if your ShoppingCart have hundreds of CartItem,every time you invoke save,you must traverse all of them to find which are update,which are add!